# Php Mail does not work if the sender mail isn't valid

Tags: php, email

In my website, I have a little contact form that uses PHP to send a mail to my personal e-mail address.
In the form, I ask the user for his e-mail address. If the address exists, the script works perfectly, and will receive the message very quickly. But if the user enters a wrong mail address, I won't never receive it. Is it normal ? Here is a little piece of my script...

```
/* Prepare Email Subject */

$email_subject = '[CONTACT FORM]' . "\t" . $title;

/* Prepare Email Message */

$email_message .= "Nom: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";
$email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($tel)."\n";
$email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($msg)."\n";

/* Prepare Email Header */

$headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

/* Send Email and redirect */

mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
header ('location: /?status=success#contact');
```

---

I would like to thank you all for your answers. I am very sorry if the problem isn't clear enough, and I hope my english is understandable (I'm a Frenchy) !

For those who don't understand what is my problem :

In my script, I put the user's mail adress in the mail header.
If the user gives me a valid e-mail, then I will receive the message, otherwise I won't.

Don't worry about the variables, this is just the last part of my script, but I verify all of them.

When I said "*only if the address exists*", I really wanted to mean that apparently, if the address is not registered, or if the domain does not exists, it does not work.
Before sending the mail, I verify if the address is "valid" by applying a Regex test.
And if I enter, for example : abcde@aeaefa.fr I won't receive the mail. That's why it is weird, the mail address format is good.

blue112, I am going to create a postmaster address, and use it to send these mails.

Comment: You should check if the mail is sent by wrapping an if around it. if(mail($email_to .....) { //executed when it's sent }. And also check if all the variables actually have a value. Also check if an error_log was generated.

Comment: *"If the address exists"* - You mean if it's "valid". If so, yes it's normal and it should be, otherwise you'd get an email from "email@example" and you wouldn't know for sure whether that's ".net", or ".com" or dot-whatever.

Comment: Ok, am I the only one not grasping the question here?

Comment: @Fred-ii- No you are not the only one, it's not exactly clear what the problem is. But gave him as many tips as we could.

Comment: @Jordy I've read the question 5, if not 10 times. I for one believe that my initial comment answers the question. It'll be up to the OP to say whether I didn't grasp the question hahaha! We've yet to hear from him, so it's anybody's guess at this point in time ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use the user's mail to send a mail.

1. It's bad practice. You are kind of usurping it's identity
2. If user uses, for instance, a gmail, and you're setting it to gmail, gmail won't trust you because he knows it never sends the email
3. They are great chances the email falls in spam box

The best way to go is a use a "valid" and trusted email to use in the "from" header field.

Also, about your script, you can wrap the `mail``function in a if to know if everything went fine during the sending.

```
if (mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers))
{
    header ('location: /?status=success#contact');
}
else
{
    echo "Sending mail failed";
}
```

This provides you no garentee that the mail succesfully arrived, however.

Comment: Pretty much what I said in the response to his original post.
And yes, he should be using PHPMailer or something similair to that.

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question; it's good practice, sure, but the OP is asking a specific question. OP only showed us a portion of the code, which is using the `clean_string()` function, which stands at containing code to prevent someone from entering an invalid Email address and other goodies for the rest of the form elements.

Answer (score 0):

Since you most likely can't actually do anything useful with the email if they have entered an invalid address, you should check that the email address is valid, there are varying degrees of annoyance for the user that you can go through to get this information to be valid:

- Using a regex to match the email address
- Asking the user to confirm their email, this captures mistypes (some annoyance)
- Ask the user to register first before they can use the contact form (big annoyance)

You could also make your mail have static From and Reply-To addresses that you own, and include the users entered email address in the actual body of the message, this ensures you actually get the email even though they may have given your contact form a rubbish email address.

Comment: That isn't true, if an anonymous suggestion is submitted or something similair to that, than the email would be irrelevant. Then once again, you don't know what he is using it for so it is hard to tell.